# How do I set a proper variable parameter right after the base URL? - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2, profile

I'm trying to build a profile right after my base URL: Example: [www.mysite.com/myprofile](http://www.mysite.com/myprofile)

I set the route like this:

$route['/?(.*)']        = "client/client_front/index/$1";

this works but now i can't access any other controller. I'm using Codeigniter 2.

Any help?

Comment: `.*` allows _any_ characters. So you need to limit this to a more narrow selection, so that there is no overlap with your existing routes.

Comment: You also can define other routes before the one shown in the question.